# 2 Bootstrap sites not background image not responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I have 2 sites I've created - How do I get the header background images to be resize correctly on mobile devices? When viewing on mobile the images are cut off on both sides.

I have this code in the header section for each:

Here is the code for each:

segregatedsunday.com

```
    #h {
    background: url(../img/header.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    padding-top: 180px;
    text-align:center;
    background-attachment: relative;
    background-position: center center;
    min-height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;

    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

whitehatdev.co

```
 #headerwrap {
    background: url(../img/header_bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-top:120px;
    text-align:center;
    background-attachment: relative;
    background-position: center center;
    min-height: 650px;
    width: 100%;

    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: when viewing my sites on mobile, the header background image is too large, ie not responsive. See http://mobiletest.me/ to view on mobile.

Comment: P.Clark.  go ahead and edit your original problem statement.  Tell us EXACTLY what is wrong.  Hint: an image is worth 1000 words.  And that mobiletest.me link is pretty worthless.  Or build up a sample webpage that exhibits the issue. etc...

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at your first example and it generally seems fine. The extra 100% background-size stuff doesn't fit the situation.  When I drag the jsfiddle larger and smaller, the image resizes dynamically like "cover" should.  Moo!

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytoargx0/)

```
 #headerwrap {
    background: url(http://www.glitters20.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Funny-Cow-37.gif) no-repeat center top;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-top:120px;
    text-align:center;
    background-attachment: relative; 
    background-position: center center;
    min-height: 250px;
    width: 100%;

    /* -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%; */

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You aren't mixing up cover and contain are you?  Its not exactly clear on what goal you are trying to achieve.  Cover and Contain will maintain aspect ratio so no image is ever distorted.

> contain
>
> The contain value specifies that regardless of the size of the
>   containing box, the background image should be scaled so that each
>   side is as large as possible while not exceeding the length of the
>   corresponding side of the container.
>
> cover
>
> The cover value specifies that the background image should be sized so
>   that it is as small as possible while ensuring that both dimensions
>   are greater than or equal to the corresponding size of the container.

Comment: when I remove the 100% entries it does resize a bit better on web but doesn't change anything on mobile devices. I tried contain instead of cover and that cuts off the image so its not filling the width of the screen (which is better in some ways).